# Get latest record by date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table called AUDIT_LOG_1 as AL1 having date as an attribute of DATE data type.
I have another table AUDIT_LOG_2 as AL2 having date as an attribute of DATE data type.

I want to compare the date attributes of both the table in a query like AL1.date = AL2.date
The comparision is not only limited to date but also to time mean 
The comparision should happen with the date and time both like 08-09-2014 16:29:42 not only on date
Lets say in table AUDIT_LOG_1 table has records as below:
08-09-2014 
08-09-2014 
08-10-2014
consider that 1st records is insert when time is 16:29:42 and second is inserted when time is 16:31:42

and in AUDIT_LOG_2 table has one row as below:
08-09-2014 
and this record is also when time is 16:29:42

so I need to get one record based on date and time match in both the table

Now since its a date type it will display day in table but actually it also has timestamp hidden.
I need a Oracle query for this.

Comment: Your question body doesn't seem to relate to the title. Just reading your title I would suggest using ROW_NUMBER(). Looking at the body it sounds like a simple join. Perhaps if you created some sample data and output we might understand your question better

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to join the to logs via the date, you can issue:

```
SELECT * FROM AL1 INNER JOIN AL2 ON (al1.date = al2.date)
```

If you are going to find the latest record (as the title of your question suggest), you can do it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM AL1 ORDER BY date DESC
```

or, if you need the results from both tables

```
( SELECT * FROM AL1
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM AL2
) ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: using = the date and time doesn't match, i want a way to match the date and its time

Comment: So you want to have a fuzzy matching between dates?

You can try to truncate the dates before comparison, but what are you exactly going to do?

Comment: i just want to compare two dates with its time

Comment: But a.date = b.date compares two dates with its time.

Comment: The only issue is, if the time of date 1 is not exactly the time of date 2. Then you have to become fuzzy in your comparison. To do this, you must have a clear understanding, how you can compare the entries - I do not understand the context and the purpose, what you want to do.